# How to use viewport height into tr of the table

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table that contains number of tr. I need to get stretched the contents based on height. So I am testing it through browser by increasing and decreasing height.Here div is working fine but table is not stretching properly.Here is the code below

```css
.test div,
.test tr {
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<!--<div class="test">
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
     <div>This is testing div</div>
    </div>
    -->
<div>
  <table class="test">
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is testing div</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: You can't set height on a tr. Give the td's the height instead.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Both div and table seem to be working fine.